# How to compare two color hash code in css file

Tags: css, saas

I have a use case where I need to compare the hash values of colors in css file like below:

```
@if $color-body-text == $color-default-text {
    :root {
        --color-body-text-light      : color-mod(wl(color-body-text) alpha(75%));
    }
} @else {
    :root {
        --color-body-text-light      : wl(color-body-text);
    }
}
```

The values are:
color-body-text: #FF525F7F
color-default-text: #FF525F7F

The flow is always going inside else block. Could someone please help in finding what is wrong with the code above?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Which preprocessor is this? Sass? And how are the variables defined?

Comment: I am sorry...I am new to this but the file extension says it's .css file

Comment: I tried this also
`
@if $color-body-text == $color-body-text {
    :root {
        --color-body-text-light      : color-mod(wl(color-body-text) alpha(75%));
    }
} @else {
    :root {
        --color-body-text-light      : wl(color-body-text);
    }
}
`
but still it's going inside else

Comment: @Deepika as @Ry asked we need to know what preprocessor youre using. You saying the file extension is `.css` sounds like youre not using a preprocessor but pure CSS which would make using a complex if-clause _impossible_.

Comment: Ok, I switched to saas processor and it seems like the same. Can't we compare the color hash codes as I did above?

Comment: Use @debug to check the value.

Comment: @Deepika Change the file extension to `.sass`, Only then it would be a sass file and you must use a sass pre-processor as well. I also see wrong way to declare variables in you file. You have use `--` e.g.,  `--color-body-text-light`. This is how we declare variables in pure `CSS`. For Sass you should use `$`.

Kindly refer to this https://sass-lang.com/documentation/variables

Though Sass is superset of CSS but still, let keep it the way it makes sense and then check

Comment: Thanks a lot guys, @debug option helped me to debug the coming value. Thanks much